# Linux piping & loop

Tags: linux, pipe, piping

Is it possible to create a loop using Linux pipes?  E.g.

> cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 | 'back to stdin cmd1'

In other words, I'd like `stdout` at `cmd3` to be connected back to `stdin` of `cmd1`.

Comment: Be aware that such loops may cause deadlocks. If a command in the loop stops reading for too long while still writing, eventually all pipes become full and block. Even the original slow command cannot write anymore.

Comment: I will be using this as a "message passing ring" (as a replacement for a 0MQ based system): I don't expect this sort of deadlock to occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a named pipe/FIFO:

```
mkfifo cmd3-to-cmd1
cmd1 < cmd3-to-cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 >> cmd3-to-cmd1
```